# Obtener el id de un elemento HTML

Tags: javascript, dom

El código es simple, a todos los elementos con la `class` A2 los mete en un `array` llamado test.

`var test = document.querySelectorAll('.A2');`

¿Se puede saber cual es el `id` de los elementos dentro de `test` y que el `alert` sea algo así `alert("El id del boto es " + test_id)`? Gracias de antemano.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Test1" class="A2" id="B1">
    <input type="button" value="test2" class="A2" id="B2">
</body>
<script>
window.onload = function (){
    var test =document.querySelectorAll('.A2')
    for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){
        test[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            alert("Hola")
        }); 
    }
}   
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder al `id` del elemento puedes usar `this`, la linea de tu alert debería ser así:

```
alert("El id del boto es "+this.id)
```

y el código te queda así:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Test1" class="A2" id="B1">
    <input type="button" value="test2" class="A2" id="B2">

</body>
<script>
window.onload = function () 
{
    var test =document.querySelectorAll('.A2')
    for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++)
    {
        test[i].addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            alert("El id del boto es "+this.id)
        }); 
    }
}   
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Ohhh muchas gracias, con esto me ayudaste mucho, que buscaba en google y buscaba pero eran tantos detalles que salia de todo menos lo que necesitaba

Comment: de nada @GatoGrisSobreElTejado (ノ・∀・)ノ, marca la respuesta como aceptada por favor si te sirvio.

Comment: dice que espere 5 min, se completa y le pico click

Answer (score 1):

El array contiene los elementos `HTML`, solamente tendrías que seleccionar la propiedad el elemento del `id`. Intenta con esto:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Test1" class="A2" id="B1">
    <input type="button" value="test2" class="A2" id="B2">

</body>
<script>
window.onload = function () 
{
    var test =document.querySelectorAll('.A2')
    for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){
        alert("El id del boto es: " + test[i].id);
    }
}   
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Ohhh muchas gracias, con esto me ayudaste mucho, que buscaba en google y buscaba pero eran tantos detalles que salia de todo menos lo que necesitaba